# How to divide the information of an array and send it to another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have this array in Javascript:

```
cars = [
  {color: red, type: sedan, name: ferrari},
  {color: blue, type: sedan, name: ferrari},
  {color: yellow, type: sedan, name: ferrari},
  {color: red, type: coupe, name: toyota},
  {color: red, type: sedan, name: toyota}
]
```

What I am trying to do is create a multidimensional array where I have the information of the first array but it looks like this:

I want to separate ferraris cars from Toyota

```
carsseparated[0] = [
  {color: red, type: sedan, name: ferrari},
  {color: blue, type: sedan, name: ferrari},
  {color: yellow, type: sedan, name: ferrari}
]

carsseparated[1] = [
  {color: red, type: coupe, name: toyota},
  {color: red, type: sedan, name: toyota}
]
```

this is what I have been coding

```
$scope.carsseparated= [];
var cont = 0;
$.each($scope.cars, function (index,value) {
  $scope.carsseparated[cont] = [value.color, value.type, value.name]
  cont = cont+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let cars = [{color: "red", type: "sedan", name: "ferrari"}, {color: "blue", type: "sedan", name: "ferrari"}, {color: "yellow", type: "sedan", name: "ferrari"}, {color: "red", type: "coupe", name: "toyota"},
            {color: "red", type: "sedan", name: "toyota"}];

let  car1 = cars.filter(val => val.name === 'ferrari');
let  car2 = cars.filter(val => val.name === 'toyota');
console.log(car1)
```

Comment: yes, I guess that may work, but I'm trying to make it dynamic, what I want to say is that, I do not want to do this: val.name === 'ferrari'
thanks for answering.